# Wordpress custom created table giving error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress site. I have added a custom table in database. Now i am using wordpress `get_results` to get the data in theme page template. Its showing error:

> WordPress database error: [Table 'test_wordpress.wp_testtable'
>   doesn't exist]

Here is my code i have written in my page template:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$data = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."testtable");
```

Comment: may you show me the complete code...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace below code after check ?

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "testtable";
$data = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table_name");
```